# Getting surveillance camera footage streamed to phone

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, camera

I am studying computer programming, but I feel that at school we are doing only stuff that work on a computer without having any connection to the outside world and it isn't all that interesting, so I gave myself a challenge. I want to make a program that streams footage from a surveillance camera to a phone. It seems a bit of a long shot, but I want to try. The thing is that, as I said, at school we are doing pretty basic stuff and with a project like this I have no idea how to even begin. A simple Google search didn't help at all.

I know how mobile apps are made, but I have no idea how to connect such devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is too general to answer. There are several protocols to achieve this. I suggest you do some research on RTSP, RTMP protocols and try to search tutorials that teach you how to implement these protocols on mobile app platforms.

Comment: Thank you! This is a ton of help.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to submit an answer?

Comment: I can help if you can give me the surveillance camera footage stream url.

Comment: Like I said, I want to do this with a camera of my own and I start at ground zero, so there is no URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience only in RTMP streaming so I am going to explain what I did then.As far as I know, there are 3 components required for streaming in RTMP:

1. **The source** - a device with the webcam that is going to generate the video streams. You might need to learn flash scripting language called ActionScript 3 and Flex to write an application that will help you to send stream to a server.
2. **The Media Server**- The source device sends its stream to the media server (in some cases, the media server is the source). You can easily do this with action script after you set up your server. If you want to have a local media server then you can install RED5 media server which is based on Java and is open-source.
3. **Client Application**- The client application can be a mobile application or a flash based web application which will connect to your media server for the stream and will display it on the client's device.Even this can be written in ActionScript/Flex.

Here is a tutorial on how you can download and setup Red5 media server: 
http://www.technogumbo.com/tutorials/Red5-Media-Server-Development-Setup-Tutorial/Red5-Media-Server-Development-Setup-Tutorial.php

You'll need to learn ActionScript / Flex for client side application and some bit of Java for server side.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted as an answer. Thank you kind stranger!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need further help. You can email me.